# Magnitude attenuation by a filter

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, window-functions, magnitude

I have a filter, with coefficients given by
$$
W=\sin((2*\pi*2*F_f*k/F_s)/(2*\pi*2*F_f*k/F_s))*h[k]
$$, where $F_f$ is the filter reference frequency, $k$ runs from $-N/2$ to $N/2$ ($N$ is the order of the filter), $F_s$ is the sampling frequency and $h[k]$ is a hamming window. For any value of N what will be the attenuation of magnitude encountered by a signal passed through it.

Comment: well, you just have to find the Fourier transform of the function and extract the amplitude, no?

Comment: Have you checked matlabs `freqz`function, in the case that `W` are your filter coefficients the function call would be `freqz(W,1)`

Comment: freqz will provide me with the amplitude and phase response of the filter, not the attenuation value, which is primarily what i am looking for.